# Selenium code working on mac while not on linux - same selenium versions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have python script using selenium working correctly on max os X M1 with selenium 4.8.2 (pipenv shell), while it does not work on linux with the same version of selenium (also pipenv shell).

The only difference between both environments are:

- mac os X is ARM (M1 processor) while Linux is x86_64 arch
- mac: python 3.10 while Linux python 3.8
- mac: chromedriver 109.0.5414.74 while Linux chromedriver 110.0.5481.77
- selenium version the same (4.8.2)

This is the core part of the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
#chrome_driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver" #used for Linux
chrome_driver_path = "/System/Volumes/Data/Users/myname/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/mac64/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver"

def get_scrape_web(data: str) -> str:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(f'https://xxxxx.com')
    l1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"test-address-view")
    l2 = l1.shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main-generic-report[id=report]")
    return l2
```

When it's working on mac i can find the corresponding element in shadow_root and return as l2, while on Linux i am getting the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"main-generic-report[id=report]"}
```

Why my code is not working on Linux ? The exact versions from Linux:

```
-bash-4.2# chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839})

-bash-4.2# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 110.0.5481.100
```

Any ideas/recommendations ?

Thanks

Comment: After navigating the url, provide some wait before interacting the element.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that with shadow_root, any hints/examples ?

Comment: OK, indeed: replaced l2 with `l2 = WebDriverWait(l1.shadow_root, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main-generic-report[id=report]")))` and it started to work fine. Thanks KunduK !